# How to integrate a Discord server into my website?

Tags: html, discord

I try to connect my website with an Discord Server. For that I use like usual the JSON API of the server and integrate this URL in my HTML code.

```
    <a href="https://discord.com/api/guilds/874961789551542272/widget.json">Discord</a>
```

If I try now to klink on the link a new brower window opens with the following message:

```
{"id": "874961789551542272", "name": "openBlog.ai", "instant_invite": null, "channels": [{"id": "874961789551542276", "name": "classroom", "position": 0}], "members": [{"id": "0", "username": "MaxHager", "discriminator": "0000", "avatar": null, "status": "online", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/widget-avatars/9_y6F7dnV8rm28_KUhVTfG7RIcFux7SZrMq7TPKbN3c/4KJuatJ4H6zoD5rJJim3pBgXHoJH2vEvVg5fnk5zjwGHyPfWRM3vxH8c33qxSu0j_byamPP74TWSjpZkrLe9g4S-DQ3WtnfdBw9T3uMbV0-gfjdY3-hUkVcyTALCl5VlwbZ6jZc2etGlQg"}], "presence_count": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works at all.
What you are doing now is linking a JSON Text file to your website, which contains text information about your server.

What i think you want is some kind of third party widget.

You can try something like this one https://github.com/Nerfact/discord-widget

Try the following

- add the code snippet to your html site
- change the server id here

  serverId: '51143782082543616',

to yours (874961789551542272)

to just get an invite link you can use something like this:

```
    <a href="<your server invite link>">
<img src="https://discord.com/api/guilds/874961789551542272/widget.png?style=banner4"/>
</a>
```

you can change the style using ?banner=X, see here

https://codepen.io/clearlyelevated/pen/xxKyoyR

Comment: I don't wanna add a widget. I just want that people can click on my Discord button from my website and then the specific server should open.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to add a simple widget which links to your server, but you need to paste your invite link from your discord